# how to check if exists via query in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have two queries and I want to check if one of the `PopulateKode` on the query A exists in the `PopulateKode` returned by query B.

How can I do it?

This is my query:

**QUERY A:**

```
 select KodePosition as PopulateKode from Position where UserLogin='winz\siti.azzahra'
```

**Resultset of A:**

```
PopulateKode
0041
0139
```

**QUERY B:**

```
 SELECT (A.IdPositiionPengirim +';'+ B.KodeJabatan)as PopulateKode
 FROM SuratKeluar as A
 join SuratKeluarD as B on A.Id=B.IdSuratKeluar
 where A.Id='60083a60-2643-45b5-8b59-c6094ec8b79d'
```

**Resultset of B:**

```
PopulateKode 
0037
0038
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `IN()` with a `UNION` so each value from query B is separate:

```
select KodePosition as PopulateKode
from Position
where UserLogin='winz\siti.azzahra'
and KodePosition IN (
    SELECT A.IdPositiionPengirim
    FROM SuratKeluar as A
    join SuratKeluarD as B on A.Id=B.IdSuratKeluar
    where A.Id='60083a60-2643-45b5-8b59-c6094ec8b79d'
    UNION
    SELECT B.KodeJabatan
    FROM SuratKeluar as A
    join SuratKeluarD as B on A.Id=B.IdSuratKeluar
    where A.Id='60083a60-2643-45b5-8b59-c6094ec8b79d')
```